Getting copies of every record in SendMessageBatchRequest - AWS SQS
We are facing an issue with consuming SQS records. We are sending batch records to SQS from ECS which is later consumed from a Lambda. I am logging every record being sent from ECS, and I can confirm it's the correct number of records, but for some reason, lambda is always consuming a copy of the original record as well. I have no idea how this copy is coming from; it is literally after a second the original one comes up in SQS. It has same body but obviously different message id.
This is the producer code:

    public void sendMessageInBatch(List<Long> authorizedTransactions) {
            List<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < authorizedTransactions.size(); i++) {
                entries.add((SendMessageBatchRequestEntry.builder().id(String.valueOf(i+1)).messageBody(String.valueOf(authorizedTransactions.get(i))).build()));
                if ((i+1) % 10 == 0) {
                    this.sendMessagesBatch(entries);
                    entries = new ArrayList<>();
                }
            }
            if (!entries.isEmpty()) {
                this.sendMessagesBatch(entries);
            }
        }

@Async
private void sendMessagesBatch(List<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry> entries) {
    List<SendMessageBatchResultEntry> successfulEntries;
    List<BatchResultErrorEntry> failedEntries;
    entries.forEach((entry) -> {
        LOG.info("ID: " + entry.id() + " Transaction: " + entry.messageBody());
    });
    try {
        SendMessageBatchRequest sendMessageBatchRequest = SendMessageBatchRequest.builder().queueUrl(queueUrl).entries(entries).build();
        SendMessageBatchResponse sendMessageBatchResponse = sqsClient.sendMessageBatch(sendMessageBatchRequest);
        if (sendMessageBatchResponse.hasSuccessful()) {
            successfulEntries = sendMessageBatchResponse.successful();
            LOG.info("Processed below entries: ");
            successfulEntries.forEach((entry) -> {
                LOG.info(entry.messageId());
            });
        }
        if (sendMessageBatchResponse.hasFailed()) {
            failedEntries = sendMessageBatchResponse.failed();
            LOG.info("Below entries failed: ");
            failedEntries.forEach((entry) -> {
                LOG.info(entry.id() + " " + entry.message());
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}


This is the infra code:

    this.pollingQueue = new Queue(this, 'auth-record-polling-queue', {
                queueName: 'auth-record-polling-queue',
                retentionPeriod: Duration.days(1),
                visibilityTimeout: Duration.minutes(10),
                deliveryDelay: Duration.seconds(15),
                deadLetterQueue: {
                    queue: this.deadLetterQueue,
                    maxReceiveCount: 2
                }
            });


Since consumer code is a lambda and too big to provide here, this is the github code repo and lambda code: Lambda Handler
I am using an idempotent wrapper around the handler...I'm not sure if that is causing the issue.
I have tried the following:
Increasing the visibility timeout of SQS
Logging producers send
Adding delay before consuming.

If you're sure that only one message is being sent, yet two message arrive with different Message IDs, then it sounds like SQS is re-sending a message that it thinks has failed. Are there any messages in the Dead Letter Queue? If so, this suggests that the message is being processed more than twice. I'd certainly suggest setting the Visibility Timeout to a larger value as a test and making sure that your Lambda function returns a success signal when processing the message so it doesn't get retried.
